# MySQL/phpMyAdmin freezes from DELIMITER

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, triggers, xampp, delimiter

Running this procedure causes MySQL (or phpMyAdmin) to freeze. I have to stop MySQL with from XAMPP command, which freezes and "is not responding" about 20 seconds before stopping. I believe this is caused by the delimiter command, which on it's own begins the problems. I have tried using a different delimiter ("//") to no effect.

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE TRIGGER coroner AFTER INSERT ON events
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE teams WHERE id = NEW.victim SET live = live-1;
UPDATE teams WHERE id = NEW.shooter SET score = score+points;
END

$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 5):

As it turns out, phpMyAdmin has a field marked "delimiter:" below the SQL query box. Using it rather than the command solves the problem. Further research explains that "DELIMITER" is not a SQL command, but a command generally implemented by all SQL ui's.

Answer (score 0):

the update command should:

```
update teams set live = live-1 where id = new.victim;
update teams where id = new.shooter set score = score+points;
```

the `where` after the `set` clause

Comment: i didn't know that mattered, thanks! but the thing stalls out after just DELIMITER $