# Why this query is not executing?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `horizon_jake`$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GPS_Distance_Meters`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`horizon_jake`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GPS_Distance_Meters`(lat1 DOUBLE, lng1 DOUBLE, lat2 DOUBLE, lng2 DOUBLE) RETURNS DOUBLE
BEGIN
    DECLARE rlo1 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE rla1 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE rlo2 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE rla2 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE dlo DOUBLE;
    DECLARE dla DOUBLE;
    DECLARE a DOUBLE;

    SET rlo1 = RADIANS(lng1);
    SET rla1 = RADIANS(lat1);
    SET rlo2 = RADIANS(lng2);
    SET rla2 = RADIANS(lat2);
    SET dlo = (rlo2 - rlo1) / 2;
    SET dla = (rla2 - rla1) / 2;
    SET a = SIN(dla) * SIN(dla) + COS(rla1) * COS(rla2) * SIN(dlo) * SIN(dlo);
    RETURN (6378137 * 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(a), SQRT(1 - a)));
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Database name: horizon_jake
Database User: horizon_jake

MySQL version: 5.1.56

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
Error

SQL query:

DELIMITER $$ USE `horizon_jake` $$ DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GPS_Distance_Meters` $$ CREATE DEFINER = `horizon_jake`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GPS_Distance_Meters` (
lat1 DOUBLE,
lng1 DOUBLE,
lat2 DOUBLE,
lng2 DOUBLE
) RETURNS DOUBLE BEGIN DECLARE rlo1 DOUBLE;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$

    USE `horizon_jake`$$

    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ' at line 1
```

Comment: Are you executing this on the MySQL command line client, or something like PHPMyAdmin?  `DELIMITER` is a feature of the command line client.

Comment: @Michael: Surely phpMyAdmin doesn't magically re-invent the MySQL command interface; it passes queries and commands through to MySQL.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal PHPMyAdmin has a separate input field for setting a delimiter. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068331/mysql-phpmyadmin-freezes-from-delimiter and others...

Comment: @Tomalak That is right, but it is the other way round: the CL client "reinvents" (extends) the interface.

Comment: @Michael: OK, so `DELIMITER` is literally a feature of the command line client (rather than of that which eventually parses/interprets most of the text going through it), and is not a feature of the equivalent interface available to PHP applications; and, thus, phpMyAdmin must re-implement it on top?

Comment: @glglgl: "re-invent" is quite different from "extend" :)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Im no MySQL expert, but isn't there something fishy about the single-quote signs used? Besides quoting object names are obtional, right?

Comment: Well, So smart! On my local machine I execute this query by PhpMyAdmin. If I simply copy the query from here and past in phpMyAdmin it will execute without any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DELIMITER` defines separator for SQL statements. `USE` is not a SQL statement and hence doesn't need to be delimited with `$$`.