# Is there any way to use DECLARE in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I try to write a simple procedure in phpmyadmin and I need to declare variables..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FARMER()
IN nume VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
    DECLARE playerid NUMBER(6);
    DECLARE suma NUMBER(3);
    DECLARE newsum NUMBER(3);
    DECLARE bonus NUMBER(3);
    SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(20-1)+1) INTO bonus;
    SELECT ID into playerid from player where nume = USERNAME;
    SELECT GOLD into suma from wallet where playerid = ID;
    newsum := suma + bonus;
END
```

Is there any way to use `DECLARE` without problems. I am not importing the procedure, I am writing it in SQL tab... I've read some things about using `DELIMITER` but I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: Keep looking.  phpMyAdmin (PMA) doesn't use the `DELIMITER` declaration,  but it seems like it might have a drop-down or something where you can select the delimiter.  The problem you'll encounter with trying to find straight answers to PMA questions is that experienced users don't use PMA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL/phpMyAdmin freezes from DELIMITER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068331/mysql-phpmyadmin-freezes-from-delimiter)

Comment: Found it. There's a drop-down "below the query box" according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2068477/1695906).